# Start timestamp of pts_time in an MPEG-TS stream is not zero

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to generate a MPEG-TS stream using the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=25 -c:a copy output1.ts
```

When examining the output1.ts using,

```
ffplay -i output1.ts -vf showinfo
```

reveals that start timestamp under pts_time is not equal to zero. it shows 1.48.

A remuxing using

```
ffmpeg -i output1.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -mpegts_copyts 1 output2.ts
```

caused the output2.ts to have a start timestamp of 0.08.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me the reason for this behaviour and how I can set the start timestamp to zero.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is very common to add an arbitrary amount of time at the start of a transport stream. The reason for this is two fold.

First, transport streams were originally intended for very long broadcasts (days or weeks. Think television stations). TS uses 33 bits to store 90kHz ticks. This makes timesamp rollovers very common (about once a day). Because the timestamp rolls over so frequently, It is generally not a good idea to rely on the time stamps as anything other than an arbitrary tick on a ever moving clock with a start time at an unknown point in the past. Think of an analog clock, and remove all markings. Without the orientation, you can not use it to tell time. But you can still use it to measure time. In other words the timestamps only have meaning relative to other timestamps in the stream. They do not exist for human convenience. They exist so the decoder can do its job.

But as to why not start at 0 anyway. TS stores pts and dts as separate values, where as other containers use a dts+cts to determine pts. So, If you have a stream with out of order (B) frames, you will encounter frames that must be decoded before time 0, and displayed after. In other words, you will have negative (rolled over) dts values at the start of the stream. To simplify the decoders job, some value larger then the largest possible cts (pts-dts) is added to the pts/dts to bring them into the positive range at the start. This is common practice, and left up to the decoder/player to apply the logic as to what time is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Let us find the answer from the MP4 specification i.e. `ISO_IEC_14496-12`
There are two types of "Box" related to calculating "pts_time":`ctts` and `stts`. Put simply, `ctts` is "base" and `stts` is the offset, we can derive the "pts_time" by adding "offset" from "base".

Here is the wording from the spec describing the `ctts`

> This box provides the offset between decoding time and composition
> time. In version 0 of this box, the decoding time must be less than the
> composition time, and the offsets are expressed as unsigned numbers
> such that CT(n) = DT(n) + CTTS(n) where CTTS(n) is the (uncompressed)
> table entry for sample n. In version 1 of this box, the composition
> timeline and the decoding timeline are still derived from each other,
> but the offsets are signed. It is recommended that for the computed
> composition timestamps, there is exactly one with the value 0 (zero).

Not that composition time and presentation time can be used interchangeably, or `pts` and `cts` are the same concept

So how it relate to the non-zero `pts_time`, Let us examine the following table **carefully**

[image]
[image]
`DT` denotes the decoding time and `CT` denotes the composition time (presentation time), `Decode delta` is not that relevant, and **`CT`=`DT`+`Composition offset`**
Now Let us search the frame with the minimum `CT`, it should be the `I1` and the `CT` is 10, not ZERO! where means the first frame starts from 10 rather than 0.

What happens if we set the `CT` of `I1` to 0? Remember that **`CT`=`DT`+`Composition offset`**, and `CT` should be non-negative, OK, we can set the `Composition offset` of `I1` to zero.

Now what is the next frame to present, it should be `B2` with the `CT` 20, because we already set the `CT` of `I1` to 0, to keep the correct order, the `CT` of `B2` should be 10 now! How can we achieve this, we can not modify `DT`, in order to hold **`CT`=`DT`+`Composition offset`**, we should set the `Composition offset` of `B2` to -10, Hah, the negative number here, as quoted before, a negative number is support in the spec but not widely support in most of the most MP4 Demultiplexer implementation. **So we choose a non-zero start over negative offset**

If you think carefully, the reason that either no-zero start or negative offset must exist is the "B-Frame", the frame should be present first and decoded later

In the end, the spec mentioned that the non-zero start is legal

> It may be true that there is no frame to compose at time 0; the
> handling of this is unspecified (systems might display the first frame
> for longer, or a suitable fill colour).

Answer (score 0):

Using buffers may make it impossible to display a stream at time 0!