# VideoJS: segment duration issue in HLS stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, video.js, http-streaming

Several customers have ran into this error during a live event, some had refreshed the page and recovered. We looked at the upstream CDN/packaging service and there were no error from them. What can cause this error?

```
VIDEOJS:,WARN:,Segment with index 9 from playlist 0-index_131.m3u8 has a duration of
95449.7176888889 when the reported duration is 6 and the target duration is 6. For HLS
content, a duration in excess of the target duration may result in playback issues. See
the HLS specification section on EXT-X-TARGETDURATION for more details:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.3.1
```

There are some reference to this error on [VideoJS open issues](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7842#issue-1305612143) page. I couldn't reproduce the error.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/blob/9f2a4de6b8b0dc068f4426fe55b82a86c69a9add/src/segment-loader.js#L506C26-L506C41) the `duration` is retrieved from `audioTimingInfo: segmentInfo.audioTimingInfo, videoTimingInfo: segmentInfo.videoTimingInfo`, does that mean encoder has sent a incorrect timing info?

Player version: 7.20.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Transport Stream` timestamps have wrapped around.

`Transport Stream` timestamps are 33 bit 90kHz counters, and

`log2((95449.7176888889-6) * 90000) = 33`

This wrap around happens at `2^33 / 90000` seconds, or `~26.5`hrs.
Was yours a very long live stream?

As [has been pointed out on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534692/22147) this is perfectly normal, and you need to keep the wrapping nature of the timestamps in mind when interpreting them (`ffmpeg` does this well, sometimes too well).

The log output tells us that `video.js` is incorrectly interpreting TS timestamps, and in fact, searching for `timestamps` on `video.js`'s issues page turns up [this](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/7070).

There's a bunch of "me too"s on there, but no progress and the issue has been marked as stale.
Pity, it shouldn't be too hard to fix.

**UPDATE**
It's actually the responsibility of a video.js sub-package called [http-streaming](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) and it has similar, tantalising [issues](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming/issues/1266)

Comment: Thank you. We ran a test stream from encoder before the event for couple days and used the same channel for actual event. `wrapping nature of the timestamps` should this be handled by the player? Around 10% of the users have seen this error and not all, is that expected?

Comment: The player should handle it. However I tried playing an HLS recording with timestamps that wrap in the 2nd segment and encountered no problems.